# Transition moving elements in grid

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up a simple grid of items in which some items are able to be toggled on and off with the click of a button.

Now, when some of the elements disappear after clicking the button, items in the grid start switching places. In the example JSFiddle below, you can see that the horizontal transitions are working perfectly, sliding in to place, but the vertical transitions are not.

I'd appreciate any idea on how to fix that / apply a transition to the moving of the elements.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item example"></div>
  <div class="item example"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="button" id="toggle">Toggle</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
  background: #385170;
}

.container {
  height: 675px;
  width: 900px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  background: #cfcfcf;
  margin: 22.5px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease, opacity .2s;
          transition: all .35s ease, opacity .2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: #ea4c89;
  border: 2px solid #ea4c89;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  -webkit-transition: color .35s, background .35s ease;
          transition: color .35s, background .35s ease;
}
.button:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #ea4c89;
}

.example {
  background: #ea4c89;
}
.example.hidden {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
          transform: scale(0, 0);
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#toggle').on('click touchstart', function() {
  $('.example').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/uqmc7jvz/3/).

Comment: How do you imagine the end result? The items animating diagonally across the screen?

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex Ya, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

That's because position of other elements depends on these inline-blocks to get laid out in the grid;

With your code when you add class `.hidden` what's actually going on is that you shrink them (`transform: scale(0, 0)`) and `set margin : 0`.

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/uqmc7jvz/4/), look what happens just setting `opacity:0`
, maybe it's even better with `visibility:hidden` property.

Comment: Ya, but your solution cancels out all the moving. I want the grid to adapt, but not have the sudden jumps in the content.

Comment: now  I understand... for the lower line making a simple transition using grid inline-blocks sliding would be impossible beacuse it's either up or down, unless you make vertical columns like masonry

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to achieve this with CSS transitions, I think it's going to involve some JavaScript like Masonry is when you change the width of your browser, for example: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

No javascript okay here you go:
**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/poi33/uqmc7jvz/5/)**

**tl;dr**
Basically its adding each position in the grid to your css. XD (would not recommend)

With the current css3 there is no good way of doing it. because adding each grid location manually is a pain in the <s>ass</s> butt.

**CSS**
propertys like `display:inline` and `float:left` cant be animated. But transform can.
How do we use this? `transform:translate3d()` is is animatable, so we use this for our grid.
Now we can set translate3d(0%, 0%, 0); for the first position and translate3d(100%, 0, 0) for the second etc.

**but this only work for horizontal elemetns:**
`translate` for both for x and y cords.
So setting `translate3d(0%, 100%, 0)` would be the first place on the next column. and 200% for the 3 column and so on.